# Replicate the Artifacts between two Jfrog Artifactories by using CURL or jfrog rt (Rest API)

Tags: release, artifactory, devops, release-management, jfrog-cli

I am trying to replicate the artifacts between two jfrog artifactories. But here we don't want to do it from the UI, can we replicate the artifacts by using curl or jfrog rt commands.

Ref:https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Replication#RepositoryReplication-WatchtheScreencast

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no, and I'll explain. You can trigger, using the REST API, an existing replication, meaning that you already configured all of the required parameters for the replication on the repository. 
You can't run a replication between two instances of Artifactory if you don't have it set up already, meaning if the repository doesn't have replication configuration, you will not be able to replicate from it.
Also, the jfrog cli will not be able to assist you in this specific scenario.

Comment: Thanks for answering,

In our scenario, we have configured the replication section in repository for a LOCAL Repository. We want to trigger it through a command, but need to limit the path prefix while executing the command. is it possible to do, please let me know

Comment: You can only set the path prefix in the repository configurations and not on during the REST API to trigger the replication.